# Select values within nested elements?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I would like to get all the `ocd:startdate` values for each `ocd:deputato` from my model.  However, as shown in the following snippet, the value is inside an `ocd:aderisce`. How can I retrieve the values?

```xml
<ocd:deputato rdf:about="deputato.rdf/d21950_9">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >RAFFAELE RUSSO, IX Legislatura della Repubblica</rdfs:label>
    <dc:description xml:lang="it">Laurea in giurisprudenza; avvocato</dc:description>
    <ocd:aderisce rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <ocd:startDate>19830712</ocd:startDate>
    </ocd:aderisce>
    …
```

Comment: Try two things: (1) load the data and print as N-Triples or Turtle to see the structure (2) try some SPARQL queries and see what hey output.  Then you'll have information to ask a specific question "I tried this and ... I wanted ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AndyS's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854878/select-in-sparql#comment33090637_21854878) is right;  it's much easier to provide help here if you provide data that we can work with.  We can mock up data, but that's not a great use of our time, and it means that you have adapt the answers we provide back to your own problem.  At any rate, in this particular case, it's not too hard.  Your data is essentially:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:ocd="urn:ocd:"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dc="urn:dc:"
    xmlns:rdfs="urn:rdfs:">
  <ocd:deputato rdf:about="urn:deputato.rdf/d21950_9">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >RAFFAELE RUSSO, IX Legislatura della Repubblica</rdfs:label>
    <dc:description xml:lang="it">Laurea in giurisprudenza; avvocato</dc:description>
    <ocd:aderisce rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <ocd:startDate>19830712</ocd:startDate>
    </ocd:aderisce>
  </ocd:deputato>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The Turtle serialization is much easier to read, however, and it's much closer to the syntax of SPARQL:

```
@prefix ocd:   <urn:ocd:> .
@prefix dc:    <urn:dc:> .
@prefix rdfs:  <urn:rdfs:> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<urn:deputato.rdf/d21950_9>
        a               ocd:deputato ;
        dc:description  "Laurea in giurisprudenza; avvocato"@it ;
        ocd:aderisce    [ ocd:startDate  "19830712" ] ;
        rdfs:label      "RAFFAELE RUSSO, IX Legislatura della Repubblica"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
```

As we can see, the `ocd:deputato` instance is is related by the property `ocd:aderisce` to another resource that has a `ocd:startDate` property (which is just a string, not an `xsd:date`).  We can extract the dates of `ocd:deputato`s with a query like this:

```
prefix ocd:   <urn:ocd:>

select ?deputato ?startDate where {
  ?deputato a ocd:deputato ;
            ocd:aderisce/ocd:startDate ?startDate .
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------
| deputato                    | startDate  |
============================================
| <urn:deputato.rdf/d21950_9> | "19830712" |
--------------------------------------------
```